# Magento 2.3.5p-1 and Elasticsearch 6.8.11 fielddata error

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

After update Magento version to 2.3.5-p1 and Elasticsearch to the 6.8.11 vesrions I got error message on the product catalog page

```
[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [updated_at] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."}]
```

This is happens because of default sorting by updated_at field which type is "text" inside elasticsearch index. Could someone help on this? Setting fielddata is not an option as I understand, because magento will created new elasticsearch indexes after magento reindex. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute which was created had type "text","boolean" and also these two options Use in Layered Navigation and Use in Search Results Layered Navigation is set to “Yes”.
On setting these two values to "No", Fixed the issue.
Try changing, "is_filterable" field in "catalog_eav_attribute" table